# React JS with Apollo GraphQL Subscriptions

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Hi I'm trying to implement subscriptions in apollo with an auth header. I keep running into issues where Im getting CORS errors.

Seems to be no way to do this.

Here's a trimmed down version of my alteration of your code:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4444/graphql",
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: "include"
  },
  request: operation => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token
      }
    });
  },
  onError: ({ networkError }) => {
    if (networkError) {
      console.log("Network Error:::", networkError);
    }
  }
});

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: ws://localhost:4444/subscriptions,
  options: {
    reconnect: true
  }
});

const link = split(
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query);
    return kind === "OperationDefinition" && operation === "subscription";
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
);
```

*Note I am trying to implement with auth

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: The Cors was just the general not authorized. I changes to credentials:included on the server and it worked. Still havent had time to work with the auth yet